# Show progressbar in listview for each thread progress

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-progressbar

I am working on an application  where user can create post and in list it show progressbar like instagram.
- when user crate another post it should show another progressbar for new post. 
How can i handle this process

Comment: any example image for this requirement please

Comment: same as instagram create post